# File chunker for C#

Tags: c#, uploader

I am looking for a good library that can take a file input from a path string and then "chunk" the file into however many chunks are needed to meet a certain size limitation that I set upfront of the chunking.

Basically just a client chunker, anybody know of one?

Comment: Isn't this something that could be done with about a dozen lines of code? Why would you need a library for it?

Comment: Sure, I guess so. But, you don't live in my development world. Having a tested library protects me from a number of nasty consequences from mistakes in my own code. I always first try to find a library to solve a problem and use my own skills second.